# Scala self implemented Boolean shows several errors

Tags: scala, boolean

I have follow the coursera course of "Funcitonal Programming Principles in Scala" by Martin Odersky. For its week4 4.2 video of "Objects Everywhere", I have follow the step to implement my own Boolean class, but the eclipse shows several errors as following:

```
package week4

object Main{

   abstract class Boolean{

       def ifThenElse[T](e1: => T, e2: => T): T

       def && (b2: => Boolean): Boolean = ifThenElse(b2,False)
       def || (b2: => Boolean): Boolean = ifThenElse(True,b2)
       def unary_!: Boolean             = ifThenElse(False,True)    //error1

       def == (b2: Boolean): Boolean = ifThenElse(b2, b2.unary_!)   //error2
       def != (b2: Boolean): Boolean = ifThenElse(b2.unary_!, b2)   //error3
   }

   object True extends Boolean{
       def ifThenElse[T](e1: => T, e2: => T): T = e1
   }

   object False extends Boolean{
       def ifThenElse[T](e1: => T, e2: => T): T = e2
   }

   def main(args: Array[String]) {
      println("Hello, world!2")
      True.ifThenElse(println("True"), println("Flase"))
   }
}
```

error1: `=` expected by identifier found.

error2:

multiple markers at this line

- illegal start of simple expression
- call-by-name parameter creation():=>b2
- value unary! is not a member of week4.Main.Boolean

error3:

multiple markers at this line

- call-by-name parameter creation():=>b2
- value unary! is not a member of week4.Main.Boolean

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Comment: Is your Scala self different from your everyday coder self?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a space between `unary_!` and the `:`

```
def unary_! : Boolean             = ifThenElse(False,True)
```

Alternatively, as pointed out by hezamu in the comments you can use parentheses (with or without the space)

```
def unary_!(): Boolean             = ifThenElse(False,True)
```

This will work although it is worth noting that [there is a convention in Scala that parentheses on a no-args method indicate that it has side effects](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html) which is not the case here.

A third option where the return type can be inferred by the compiler (as is the case in this example) is to omit the return type entirely:

```
def unary_! = ifThenElse(False, True)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use parenthesis instead of a space. Makes it a bit readable that way, at least for myself.

`def unary_!(): Boolean             = ifThenElse(False,True)    //error1`

Comment: It's a silly error, thanks for your answer and I think hezamu's suggestion is one of the "best practice".

Comment: @hezamu: a method with 0 parameter lists is not the same as a method with 1 parameter list, even if that one parameter list is empty. In other words, your suggestion does *not* just fix the problem, it also changes the signature of the method.